# How can i iterate in a while my database data, since i need to fetch it from mutiple tables

Tags: php, sql

I have this 3 tables in my DB, and I want to fetch the data to put it in a while loop, I know how to make a `msqli_fetch_assoc()` in the loop and get the data, but since we are talking about 3 tables that are connected, how can I get the data from the others? where can I put the code?

```php
 <?php

        require_once('conexao.php');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `viatura`";
        $sql1 = "SELECT marcaviatura.nome, viatura.matricula FROM marcaviatura INNER JOIN viatura ON viatura.matricula=marcaviatura.matviatura WHERE matviatura LIKE ''";
        $sql2 = "";
        $busca = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

        //if (musqli_num_rows($busca) > 0) {


            ?>

      <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
      <th>Marca</th>
      <th>Modelo</th>
      <th>Matricula</th>
      <th>Cilindrada </th>
      <th>Tipo de Viatura</th>
      <th>Livrete</th>
      <th>Ano</th>
      <th>Inicio Seguro</th>
      <th>Fim Seguro</th>
      <th>Apolice Frota</th>
      <th>Apolice</th>
      <th>Obs</th>
      <th>GPL L.P</th>
      <th>Ano Amo</th>
      <th>Imagem</th>
     <th>Observações</th>
            <th>EDITAR </th>
            <th>EXCLUIR </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($busca) && $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc()) {

         ?>

               <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['marca'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['modelo'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['matricula'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['cilindrada'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['tipo'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['livrete'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ano'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['inicio_seguro'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['fim_seguro'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['apolice_frota'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['apolice'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['seguradora'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['obs'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['gpl_l_p'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ano_amo'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['rec'];?></td>
            <!--<td><//?php echo'<img src="upload/'.$row['imagem'].'" width="100px;" heigth ="100px;" alt="Imagem">'?></td>-->
            <td><?php echo $row['observacoes'];?></td>
```

viatura(1 to many)marcaviatura(1 to many)modelo, viatura is a vehicle, marcaviatura is the brand, and modelo is the brand model, just to give you some context.

In the echos `$row` from marca and modelo, I need it to be the "brand" from the other table with that license plate(matricula) in that iteration, and the same goes for the models.